# In jupyter notebook, i have opened a csv file using pandas that has data related to games including their last update date

Tags: python, pandas, csv, syntax, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook, i have opened a csv file using pandas that has data related to games including their last update date. I want to drop all the rows that have their last update date < 6 months. What would be the syntax for it?

The column name is current version release date. And the date format is dd/mm/yyyy.

the csv file has 2240 rows. and i want to delete rows where the date is within a time frame of 6 months from now, i.e., all the dates between november 25 and april 25 have to be deleted.

Sample data:

```
Date
20/05/2017
15/01/2020
13/05/2018
01/11/2019
.
.
15/02/2019
13/03/2020
```

2240 rows in such manner

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: after printing filename.dtypes the column comes out to be an oobject and dtype='int64'

Comment: What return `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: Int64Index([    0,     1,     2,     3,    11,    12,    13,    14,    17,
               18,
            ...
            16525, 16596, 16629, 16647, 16690, 16694, 16718, 16724, 16729,
            16874],
           dtype='int64', length=2241)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter by column `Date` converted to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

now = pd.Timestamp.now().floor('D')
previous =  now - pd.DateOffset(months=6)

df1 = df[(df['Date'] < previous) | (df['Date'] > now)]
print (df1)
        Date
0 2017-05-20
2 2018-05-13
4 2019-02-15
```

For datetimes in strings format use:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime(%d/%m/%Y)
```

Comment: the csv file has 2240 rows. and i want to delete rows where the date is within a time frame of 6 months from now, i.e., all the dates between november 25 and april 25 have to be deleted.

Comment: @VivekBhadula - Do you check comment under question?

Comment: @VivekBhadula - If is possible create some sample data ;) your code, what you try and expected output

Comment: @VivekBhadula - Answer was changed, can you test it?

Comment: thanks. it worked. but looks like there was no row within 6 months time frame xD. just the format changed in the column. it is now showing yyyy-mm-dd instead of dd/mm/yyyy. how do i get it back?

Comment: @VivekBhadula - Answer was edited. Btw, is not possible in python custom format of datetimes, always for custom formats are strings